# Doctrine DQL Search query

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, doctrine, dql

I have this DB structure:

```
- Announcement table
- Equipement table
```

there is a many to many relation between the two table, when i execute a doctrine query to search some announcement that have a specific equipement i got 0 records

this is my DQL:

```
SELECT a FROM Entity\Announcement a JOIN LEFT JOIN a.comfortEquipements aces
and aces.identifier = 1"
```

1: is the identifier of the desired equipement, 
at this stage everything is work fine but when i add some other criteria it return 0 records

Example:

```
SELECT a FROM Entity\Announcement a JOIN LEFT JOIN a.comfortEquipements aces
and aces.identifier = 1 and aces.identifier = 2"
```

Comment: try (aces.identifier = 1 OR aces.identifier = 2) instead of AND

Comment: How do You build Your DQL within PHP? Use `OR` in second query as @JapanPro proposed.

Comment: @shadyyx this is just the doctrine query,

Comment: @JapanPro, i tried "OR", it work but there is another problem: I have announcement 1 that contain two equipements (aces.identifier 1 and 2) and announcement 2 that contain only 1 equipement, after executing your query i have 2 records, but it should be retrieve only one recrod that contain the 2 equipements.

Comment: i look for a solution like this : .... where equi1 IN (aces) but it doesen't work,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
SELECT a FROM Entity\Announcement a JOIN LEFT a.comfortEquipements aces WHERE aces.identifier IN(1, 2)
```

Edit: To select only announcement with dql that have all equipements is not possible.